# Error with the plugin carousel when navigate to another page (using Durandal)

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, durandal

I have a project with Durandal SPA template. I use a carousel element in my page:

```
var compositionComplete = function () {
    $('.testimonials-carousel').carousel({
            namespace: "mr-rotato" // Defaults to “carousel”.
    });
}
```

;
Here is the plugin: http://wil.to/3a

It works pretty well whenever I stay on the page. If I navigate to another page (which don't use this carousel) I got an error.

Error: JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'match' of undefined or null reference

The errors is located here (in the carousel.js):

```
(function( $, undefined ) {
var inst = 0;

$.fn.getPercentage = function() {
    var oPercent = this.attr('style').match(/margin\-left:(.*[0-9])/i) && parseInt(RegExp.$1);

    return oPercent;
};
```

The problem is located on the `var oPercent = this.attr('style')...` line. In break mode if I inspect the `this.attr('style')` it is undefined that's why I have the error.

I don't know what to do...

**My question: do I have to dispose (or something like that) before leaving my page to avoid errors?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by scoping the carousel to the current view and see if that improves the situation.

```
var compositionComplete = function (view) {
    $('.testimonials-carousel', view).carousel({
            namespace: "mr-rotato" // Defaults to “carousel”.
    });
}
```

Assuming the model returns a constructor and cacheViews is set to false that should automatically remove the view (including carousel) from the DOM when switching to another view.

If there are artifacts left outside the scoped view (e.g. some plugins have the tendency to append elements to the body) it might be required to clean those up in the `detached` callback.